# How to access images in Adobe Lightroom CC cloud?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, photo, lightroom

so I've been wondering if there is some kind of API to access the photos I have saved in the cloud in Lightroom CC. Google wasn't much help with this.

I know that from Lightroom Classic this can be done using SQL and the `.lrcat` file. But is there anyway to access the photos saved in the cloud by the newer Lightroom CC? JPEG previews are all I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can find of the adobe APIs on Adobe.io: 
https://www.adobe.io/

Specifically, you'll want the Lightroom API (there is also an API for Lightroom Classic): 
https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/lightroom.html

The documentation for the Lightroom API can be found here:
https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/lightroom/docs.html

API Reference docs are here:
https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/lightroom/apidocs.html

After authenticating, you would use the catalog endpoint to retrieve your photos (assets).

Also: Lightroom API GitHub
https://github.com/AdobeDocs/lightroom-api-docs

Enjoy!